# Sorting after aggregating in R

Tags: r, sorting

I first used `aggregate` to get the mean of one column in a data frame, per another column:

```
meanDemVoteHouseState <- aggregate(congress$X2012.House.Dem.vote, 
                          by = list(state = congress$state),
                                   FUN = mean)
```

I then wanted to print this in order. First I looked at the new data frame

```
str(meanDemVoteHouseState)
```

and got

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ state: chr  "AK" "AL" "AR" "AZ" ...
 $ x    : num  0.29 0.34 0.29 0.462 0.566 ...
```

apparently, the new variable is now called "x".

But when I tried to sort on that:

```
meanDemVoteHouseState[order(x),]
```

I got an error "object 'x' not found".

I tried a number of other things, but nothing worked.

What am I missing ?

Comment: can you give a sample of congress data ?

Comment: `meanDemVoteHouseState[with(meanDemVoteHouseState, order(x)), ]` or `meanDemVoteHouseState[order(meanDemVoteHouseState$x), ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
 meanDemVoteHouseState[order(meanDemVoteHouseState[,"x"]),]
```

If you do it in two steps in becomes clearer

```
 myind <- order(meanDemVoteHouseState[,"x"])   # need 'x' fully qualified
 meanDemVoteHouseState[myind, ]
```

Or use things like `with()` ...

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier to just do

```
meanDemVoteHouseState <- aggregate(X2012.House.Dem.vote ~ state,
                                   data = congress, FUN = mean)
```

Which would maintain the variable name (such as it is). You'd still need to sort, say with

```
ord <- with(meanDemVoteHouseState, order(X2012.House.Dem.vote))
meanDemVoteHouseState <- meanDemVoteHouseState[ord, ]
```

And at this point you may want to choose some shorter names for variables and objects.

Comment: Thanks.  That would work too.  I may wind up changing the variable names to more sensible things.